# String going out off the screen

Tags: html, css, xslt

I am passing some string from one screen to another and i am able to achieve that.The value is passed from first screen to second screen. On first screen the user gives an input and the input is displayed on second screen. The only problem i am getting is at the second screen when the user has given some input like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" the value goes out of the screen without any scrollbar to scroll through it.
I am using XSLT 1.0 and i am catching my value in `<pre>` tag to preserve the white spaces and new line and something like

`<pre><xsl:value-of select="data"/></pre>`.

Is there any other way to get the values while preserving white spaces and new Lines and which shows the data inside the screen only?? Thanks in advance

Let me know if any other information is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a size or maximum size to your `pre` element with CSS and set its `overflow` property to `scroll`:

```
pre {
  width : 200px;
  overflow : scroll;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ThonyVezbe/pen/eYJKzbW